# Ambiguous type class returning itself in function?

Tags: class, haskell

I was making a  String Parser, while the way I did this is not optimal, as it goes over the String multiple times etc. I have encountered something I believe is weird, in Haskell.

```
 type LeftoverString = String
type Match = String

class Parser pars where
    findMatch::pars -> String -> (Match,LeftoverString)
    tokenName::pars -> String
    isRecursive::pars -> Bool
    recursiveParsers:: Parser p => pars -> [[p]]
    recursiveFromMatch:: pars -> String -> String
    isRecursive x = False
    recursiveParsers x = []
    recursiveFromMatch x y = y

type TokenName = String
data ParseTree = TokenLeaf Match TokenName | TokenNode TokenName [ParseTree] deriving Show

findFirstMatch::Parser a => [a] -> String ->(a,Match,LeftoverString)
findFirstMatch [] _                             = error "could not match String"
findFirstMatch (x:xs) str   | match /= ""       = (x,match,leftovers)
                            | otherwise         = findFirstMatch xs str
                                where
                                    (match,leftovers) = findMatch x str

generateTree::Parser a => a -> String -> ParseTree
generateTree pars str = head $ generateTree' [[pars]] str

test::Parser a => a -> [[a]]
test x = recursiveParsers x

generateTree'::Parser a => [[a]] -> String -> [ParseTree]
generateTree'  []    _                          = []
generateTree' (x:xs) str | isRecursive parser   = recTok:parseTreeRest
                         | otherwise            = leafTok:parseTreeRest
                    where 
                        (parser,match,leftovers)=findFirstMatch x str
                        tok = tokenName parser
                        parseTreeRest = (generateTree' xs leftovers)
                        recTok = TokenNode tok $ generateTree' (test parser) (recursiveFromMatch parser match)
                        leafTok = TokenLeaf match tok
```

As one can see, `recursiveParsers` in Parser returns a list of list of Parser instances

In the code you see this:

```
test::Parser a => a -> [[a]]
test x = recursiveParsers x
```

This is used in the where of `generateTree'` in recTok
As one can see, test (basically) is a synonym for recursiveParsers x

however - in the where, if I replace:

```
recTok = TokenNode tok $ generateTree' (test parser) (recursiveFromMatch parser match)
```

with

```
recTok = TokenNode tok $ generateTree' (recursiveParsers parser) (recursiveFromMatch parser match)
```

the compiler generates an error of ambiguous types.

The error is:

```
StringParser.hs:42:50:
    Could not deduce (Parser a0) arising from a use of generateTree'
    from the context (Parser a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 generateTree' :: Parser a => [[a]] -> String -> [ParseTree]
      at StringParser.hs:34:16-57
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `generateTree'
         (recursiveParsers parser) (recursiveFromMatch parser match)'
    In the expression:
      TokenNode tok
      $ generateTree'
          (recursiveParsers parser) (recursiveFromMatch parser match)
    In an equation for `recTok':
        recTok
          = TokenNode tok
            $ generateTree'
                (recursiveParsers parser) (recursiveFromMatch parser match)
```

Why does the compiler require a synonym for the function recursiveParsers for it to work?

Second question, I believe I am totally doing this wrong with trying to use Class to force a parser to have certain functions? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: "Is there another way to do this?" Turn your `Parser` class into a record. Or just give the expression `recursiveParsers parser` a type annotation.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, you are trying to use Haskell type classes as if they were OOP classes. They are not.

Roughly put, a type class is a collection of types. Its closest OOP analogous is a Java-style interface (not a class). As with Java interfaces, type classes have little use on their own unless there are some implementations (`instance`s) for them elsewhere (in Java, we want some classes to implement the interfaces).

Note the plural "implementations". Most often, we use type classes only if we can think of several ways to satisfy their interface. The type class `Num` is inhabited by `Int, Integer, Float, Double, ...`; the class `Show` by `String, Char, Bool, Int, ...`.

If we only have one sensible implementation, there's no need to use a type class.

In your specific example: what would you expect the implementations (plural) of your type class?

Also, I believe you misunderstand the type of the method

```
recursiveParsers:: Parser p => pars -> [[p]]
```

Outside the type class, this method is accessible with signature

```
recursiveParsers:: (Parser p1, Parser p2) => p1 -> [[p2]]
```

which looks wrong to me: the above means that the caller of that method can change any parser `p1` into a list of parsers `[[p2]]` where *both* `p1` and `p2` are chosen by the caller. In particular, it does *not* mean that it returns a list-of-lists of "some parser".

Any call to such method will need to specify, in its context, what `p2` is chosen to be.

This technical fact aside, I think the whole approach should be redesigned.

Comment: What I'm trying to do? People can write their own instances. It's a module. IE if I want an IntParser I could write the functions so that it accepts and strings with only numbers. if I wanted some kind of Parser that Accepts String of `"("IntParser","IntParser")"` it could say it accepted String that look like that, It would define isRecursive as True, and recursiveParsers would be [[IntParser],[IntParser]].

These instance implementations are given in another file, possibly by someone else.

what I want:
ParseTree accepts some kind of thing that has those functions. Class seems the best

Comment: Sorry, second comment. I do see how it looks weird. Basically something that is a Parser would mostly be a Datatype having exactly one constructor with no variables or types. it would simply implement parser providing the functions. data IntParser = IntParser ... instance Parser IntParser where ... bla bla

Comment: "People can write their own instances." Instead, write a function `parse` that accepts a `Parser a` record. `data Parser a = Parser { isRecursive :: Bool, parse :: String -> a, …}`. A typeclass is absolutely not what you should be using here.